# Not able to convert string to JSON in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I've a string in JSON format. I'm trying to iterate it. I have validate the string whether its JSON or not. It is fine. But, when I try to iterate it, it throws me error .

Here is my

```
var string = '[{"id":7,"userId":"123","courseId":"C4","courseValue":"{\"color\": \"blue\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}"},{"id":8,"userId":"123","courseId":"C5","courseValue":"{\"color\": \"green\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}"}]';
```

Here is the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/40/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having unwanted double string in values. Corrected json string is here

```
var string = '[{"id":7,"userId":"123","courseId":"C4","courseValue":{\"color\": \"blue\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}},{"id":8,"userId":"123","courseId":"C5","courseValue":{\"color\": \"green\",\"value\": \"#f00\"}}]';
```

Comment: Hey Sridhar, What was the issue?

Comment: you are including courseValue in double quotes which is not required. I removed double quotes in courseValue i.e "courseValue":{\"color\" instead of "courseValue":"{\"color\"...

Comment: you beat me to it, I was busy removing the unrequired escape of ".

Comment: But, thats what I get on my client.

Comment: for sure it will not execute. Whoever return that code on server is doing a mistake. As mentioned by Omri Aharon, it is the ideal way of representing a json. If this solution works fro you, please accept my answer.

Comment: I accept your answer. I need to check the server code then.

Comment: Also per Omri Aharon response, if you remove first and last single quotes, you no need to do a JSON.parse separately.

Answer (score 1):

You have taken some JSON and wrapped `'` around it to try to make it a JavaScript string literal.

Some characters have special meaning in JavaScript string literals (such as `\` which starts an escape sequence). You have failed to escape them within the string.

Consequently, to take an example:

```
"{\"color\":…
```

… when parsed as part of the JavaScript string literal becomes:

```
"{"color":…
```

… which isn't valid JSON.

You need to escape the special characters for the JavaScript string literal.

Better yet, restructure your JSON so that it doesn't contain values which are encoded as JSON themselves. Use an object instead of a string containing JSON representing an object.

Comment: What should I do with that string now? I will get the same JSON object to my client

Comment: What would be the correct structure of that string?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var string = '[{"id":7,"userId":"123","courseId":"C4","courseValue":{"color": "blue","value": "#f00"}},{"id":8,"userId":"123","courseId":"C5","courseValue":{"color": "green","value": "#f00"}}]';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to wrap the object with `"` nor escape it.

What you need is this:

```
var string = '[{"id":7,"userId":"123","courseId":"C4","courseValue":{"color": "blue","value": "#f00"}},{"id":8,"userId":"123","courseId":"C5","courseValue":{"color": "green","value": "#f00"}}]';
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hLkUz/41/)

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure if you intend to escape the JSON within courseValue. However it seems like the escaping of the nested objects is the problem. This works 
http://jsbin.com/mekiwalidu/edit?js,console,output

```
var string = '[{"id":7,"userId":"123","courseId":"C4","courseValue":{"color": "blue","value": "#f00"}},{"id":8,"userId":"123","courseId":"C5","courseValue":{"color": "green","value": "#f00"}}]';

var obj = JSON.parse(string);
console.log(obj);
```

Comment: Please put code here to avoid downvoting. Links go stale